# Android - Data from DialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I am trying to send data from one fragmentdialog where I implemented a DatePicker to a regular fragment. I am doing this by using an interface. 
I am getting an error and I don't know what i am doing wrong. The error is "cannot be resolved" with the setDatePickerEvents in the onClick method.

**FirstFragment**:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements 
   DateFragment.DatePickerEvent {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    EditText date= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
            picker.setDatePickerEvents(FirstFragment.this);
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDateSeletcted(String date) {
    String sDate= date;
    EditText dp = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    dp.setText(sDate);
 }
}
```

**DatePickerFragment:**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {
int year, month, day;

public interface DatePickerEvent{
    void onDateSeletcted(String date);
}

DatePickerEvent dpe;

public void setDatePickerEvents(DatePickerEvent dpe){
    this.dpe = dpe;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    dpe.onDateSeletcted(formattedDate);

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is named DatePicker. Not DatePickerFragment.
In your onClick change the instantiation line to

`new DatePicker();`

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake when i wrote the code in this post. This does not solve the error